# Migrate to Angular 9 with webpack from Angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, webpack

**This is not a question i just want to share my experience!**

1. You need to upgrade your dependencies in `package.json`

-all angular dependencies to version 9
-add this dependencies:

```
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.900.4",
"@angular-builders/custom-webpack": "^9.0.0",
"raw-loader": "^4.0.0",
"sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
"ts-loader": "^6.2.1",
"typescript": "~3.7.5",
"webpack": "^4.41.6",
"webpack-cli": "^3.3.11",
"webpack-dev-server": "^3.10.3",
"angular2-template-loader": "^0.6.2",
"css-loader": "^3.4.2",
"html-loader": "^0.5.5",
"html-webpack-plugin": "3.2.0",
"mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.9.0",
"to-string-loader": "^1.1.6"
```

2.Create `webpack.config.js`
(this is mine)

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin')
const path = require('path');
const  isDevelopment = process.env.WEBPACK_MODE !== 'production'
module.exports = {
  entry: './src/main.ts',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'app.bundle.js'
  },
  resolve:{
    extensions: ['.ts','.js','.scss']
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        use: ['ts-loader', 'angular2-template-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: 'html-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        exclude: [/node_modules/, /\.global\.scss$/],
        use: ["to-string-loader", "css-loader", "sass-loader"]
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({template: './src/index.html'}),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: isDevelopment ? '[name].css' : '[name].[hash].css',
        chunkFilename: isDevelopment ? '[id].css' : '[id].[hash].css'
     })
  ]
}
```

3.Change build script in package json to used webpack
ex:

```
"start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --open",
 "build": "webpack --mode development",
 "build_prod": "webpack --mode production",
 "watch": "webpack-dev-server --hot --inline --progress --colors --watch-poll"
```

4.Change your `angular.json` (if you have angular-cli you need to migrate first)

```
"build": {
      "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser",
      "options": {
        "customWebpackConfig": {
          "path": "./webpack.config.js",
          "replaceDuplicatePlugins": true
        }
      },
```

5.Import polyfills in `main.ts`

Comment: How nice of you to share, thanks :) However, since this is not a question and there is no problem, well, it is off-topic and is likely to be closed for this reason...

Comment: Could you post your answer in the answer section instead of the question?  It seems like people have found it useful, but right now it's in the wrong spot.

Answer (score 0):

You need to upgrade your dependencies in package.json
-all angular dependencies to version 9
-add these dependencies:

```
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.900.4",
"@angular-builders/custom-webpack": "^9.0.0",
"raw-loader": "^4.0.0",
"sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
"ts-loader": "^6.2.1",
"typescript": "~3.7.5",
"webpack": "^4.41.6",
"webpack-cli": "^3.3.11",
"webpack-dev-server": "^3.10.3",
"angular2-template-loader": "^0.6.2",
"css-loader": "^3.4.2",
"html-loader": "^0.5.5",
"html-webpack-plugin": "3.2.0",
"mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.9.0",
"to-string-loader": "^1.1.6"
```

2.Create webpack.config.js (this is mine)

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin')
const path = require('path');
const  isDevelopment = process.env.WEBPACK_MODE !== 'production'
module.exports = {
  entry: './src/main.ts',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'app.bundle.js'
  },
  resolve:{
    extensions: ['.ts','.js','.scss']
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        use: ['ts-loader', 'angular2-template-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: 'html-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        exclude: [/node_modules/, /\.global\.scss$/],
        use: ["to-string-loader", "css-loader", "sass-loader"]
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({template: './src/index.html'}),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: isDevelopment ? '[name].css' : '[name].[hash].css',
        chunkFilename: isDevelopment ? '[id].css' : '[id].[hash].css'
     })
  ]
}
```

3. Change build script in package JSON to used webpack ex:

   "start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --open",
   "build": "webpack --mode development",
   "build_prod": "webpack --mode production",
   "watch": "webpack-dev-server --hot --inline --progress --colors --watch-poll"
4. Change your angular.json (if you have angular-cli you need to migrate first)

   "build": {
   "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser",
   "options": {
   "customWebpackConfig": {
   "path": "./webpack.config.js",
   "replaceDuplicatePlugins": true
   }
   },
5. Import polyfills in main.ts